# django.db.utils.OperationalError no such table, but table has been created

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, migration

I'm working with Django 1.6.5 and I have a problem with the table.
I wrote the code (I added a class to the application):

```
class Season(Season):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I made:

```
python manage.py schemamigration events --auto

python manage.py migrate events
```

I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table events_season
```

But when I execute: `python manage.py migrate --list` everything indicates that the table is created and migrated.

Comment: Is this code running on Heroku, by any chance?

Comment: I am try working with this on my local machine

Comment: try: python manage.py migrate events --fake